# How to pass parameter to pipeline in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, fetchxml

I have a file in azure data lake in which datetime is stored, so I want to pass that datetime to the pipeline as a parameter in azure data factory and use that parameter in xml query used in pipeline. How can I do that and use that parameter in a query in pipeline?

Here the the condition of fetch xml query in which i want to use that parameter

"condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="2018-08-20T22:10:35.1065671-07:00""

In above condition I have used static datetime, which I want dynamically from parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use [ADF V2 UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal) to author the pipeline.
You could use a [lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#type-properties) to read the datetime from azure data lake and then reference the output of the lookup activity.

@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0

Lookup1 is your look up activity name. Prop_0 is your data header name. You could use debug button to check the output of your lookup activity.

```js
'"condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="@{activity(\'Lookup1\').output.firstRow.Prop_0}"'
```

[image]

Comment: Here is the output from datalake get in lookup activity {
    "firstRow": {
        "lastmod": "2018-08-22T01:30:45Z"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US)"
} so i have added condition as =  condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="@{activity(\'Lookup1\').output.firstRow.lastmod}" but it is showing error as ""code":"BadRequest","message":"The expression 'activity(\\Lookup1\\).output.firstRow.lastmod' is not valid: the string character '\\' at position '9' is not expected."

Comment: Please remove the \ around the lookup1 if you input it in UI. It will automatically help you escape the ‘